# What is the English word for "street along a river bank"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the English word for a regular city street that happens to be situated along a river?

(For the record, the Russian word is *набережная*, but I can't seem to find the appropriate translation.)

Comment: набережная translates as "embankment", though.

Comment: @Kris yes, but the [wikipedia definition of embankment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embankment_%28transportation%29) doesn't really fit.

Comment: It is often named *the Strand* (BrE) from the Irish *strand* : The shore of a sea, lake, or large river. "**Strand**, often called **the Strand,** is a major thoroughfare in the City of Westminster in central London that forms part of the A4 road. ... Strand forms part of the Northbank business improvement district." ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand,_London )

Comment: Waterfront, Quay?

Comment: Here in California the typical name for this kind of streets is "Embarcadero" (not actually English :) )

Comment: All the suggestions are not quite right so I am concluding there is no such noun in English. However you can use the adjective riverside (riverside street, riverside apartment etc).

Comment: _Strand_ is of Germanic origin (German, Dutch), imported into English.

Comment: "Strand" is not "from the Irish", nor is it "imported". It is Old English, general Germanic, and has Indo-European cognates, in short: a true-blooded English word.

Comment: etymonline says what fdb does. Interestingly, it adds: "Strictly, the part of a shore that lies between the tide-marks. Formerly also used of river banks." http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=strand&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: @PhilPerry, native, non-imported English words are also of Germanic origin (or at least ancestry), since English _is_ Germanic.

Comment: Just to add a few more foreign words that have made it more or less fully into the English language, Spanish gives us two good words for this exact type of street: ***paseo*** and ***rambla*** (though both can just as well be along the coast, by the ocean, rather than specifically on the banks of a _river_).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here in Australia we call them *esplanades*, although as [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esplanade) says,  that really refers to

> a long, open, level area, usually next to a river or large body of water, where people may walk.

A related word is *promenade*.

Comment: That sounds similar to the American term riverwalk, which refers to a path or boardwalk along a river, typically with a row of shops along it. The term is occasionally used to include the street behind the shops.

Comment: I think *promenade* is  more seashore; "A place for walking or promenading; a paved public walk, esp. one along the seafront at a resort" (OED).

Comment: Here is Boston USA we have an esplanade alongside the river, though it is for walking rather than driving.

Answer (score 11):

You can find these streets referred to as **river roads**, often with *River Road* or *River Street* being part of their proper names. There are [many books](https://www.google.com/search?q=river%20road&biw=1440&bih=764&tbm=bks&ei=1e4nU-K8K4SyqgHev4D4Aw&start=0&sa=N) that use the term, including *[The Majesty of the River Road](http://books.google.com/books?id=QgwTCZA5h1YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=river%20road&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1e4nU-K8K4SyqgHev4D4Aw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=river%20road&f=false)*, where the introduction begins

> Along the road that follows the course of the Mississippi stand many majestic structures that have withstood the test of time.

Here a picture where it's part of the proper name, Savannah, Georgia's (USA) *River Street* ([ref](http://www.railwaypreservation.com/vintagetrolley/savannah.htm))
[image: River Street, Savannah]

While *embankment* might describe a bank, mound, dike, levee, or the like, and is typically raised to hold back water, it may carry a roadway or railway, but not necessarily ([ref](http://markchanski.com/2011/07/25/the-fear-of-god-a-protecting-safeguard/)):

[image]

Comment: Great pics @Jim. Enjoyed seeing the Melbourne tram in Savannah!

Comment: Ha! You are right! I had to check it out myself. [A re-conditioned 1925 W5 Melbourne streetcar.](http://www.metrojacksonville.com/article/2009-sep-streetcars-return-to-savannah)

Comment: Just out of curiosity...Why was the embankment made around that house?  The water's obviously flooded, so it's not just somebody wanting their own private island in the middel of the river somehwere.  But since the water's flooded, they wouldn't have had time to make the embankment as an emergency measure.

Comment: Probably imminent flooding was expected. They are probably in a floodplain and had the resources to put that embankment or levee in just in time. It looks freshly made. Most people and not so lucky and unlucky at the same time.

Answer (score 10):

London has the roads called Victoria Embankment and the Albert Embankment on opposite sides of the river; it also has the Strand — *strand* as a noun refers to a beach.

“The Embankment” generally means the path along the south side of the Thames between Westminster Bridge and Lambeth Bridge, opposite the Palace of Westminster.

As the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embankment_%28transportation%29) explains, *Embankment* does mean an earthwork built to contain a river or support a railway or road; but (as the article notes) can also refer to a roadway atop such a structure. Usually, such a use is qualified as in *Victoria/Albert/Chelsea Embankment*.

Comment: There's also _bund_, which is essentially the same as _embankment_. The most famous is "The Bund" in Shanghai.

Comment: I don't agree at all that "The Embankment" generally means the south side. The tube stop "Embankment" is on the north side after all.

Answer (score 5):

The commentators have already given viable suggestions. I'd like to add towpath, which has the exact relationship you describe - a street or path that runs alongside a river or canal, which horses used to walk along, pulling or towing barges behind them, hence the name.

According to [this source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Towpath?s=t), you can also use 'towing path', although that's less common in my experience.

Comment: Is *towpath* used for streets that were not formally literal tow paths?

Answer (score 2):

There is no word that means exactly and unambiguously “street that happens to be along a river bank”, but there are several words that can be used to refer to a river bank where pedestrians or vehicles can tread (not necessarily both). Which word is used in a given place is a matter of regional variation and historical happenstance. These words have an etymological connotation that may or may not apply in any given use.

A *[quay](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quay)*, *[wharf](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wharf)*, *[dock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dock)* or *[pier](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pier)* is an area along a river or sea side where boats can load and unload cargo. A quay or dock is artificial, a wharf can be either artificial or natural. These words can refer to the wooden or stone (or earth, for a quay) structure where boats moor, or to the road that runs alongside the shore, or to a larger area going up to the whole neighborhood (as in [Canary Wharf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_Wharf) in the London [Docklands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Docklands)). Among these, I think *quay* is the one most commonly used as a street name. [This list of names](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/sitemap/streets_k.html) features example of all these terms.

An *[embankment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embankment)* is etymologically a [levee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levee), a raised band of earth on the side of the river which can be natural or artificial. Usually pedestrians or vehicles can move on the embankment or on a road next to it. By extension, any river-side road can be called an embankment. The London [*Embankment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_Embankment) is a famous example; several streets bear that name (*Victoria Embankment*, *Chelsea Embankment*).

Regarding some other words that have been mentioned in this thread, a *[terrace](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terrace)* is a raised bank of earth (among other meanings). An *[esplanade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esplanade)* is a wide space or street. Both terms can be used for a waterfront street, but they do not imply that the street is near water, so they are best avoided as a translation. [psmears](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3405/psmears) also suggests *[corniche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corniche)*, a road at the top of a cliff, often but not always along a river or sea shore.

You can also refer to such a street using a qualifier: it is simply a *[riverside](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riverside) street*, or a *river street* or *river road*.

If there is no local usage to fall back on, I would go with *embankment* for a riverside road in the countryside, or a *quay* in a city, especially but not exclusively if boats can moor.

Comment: You might also add "corniche" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corniche ...

Answer (score -1):

try  levee thats one of the non slang words southerners use

Comment: The levee is the embankment next to the river, not the road.

Comment: You drive your Chevy *to* the levee, not along the levee. In Canada, on New Year's Day, you can drive your Chevy to the levée. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev%C3%A9e_%28event%29

Comment: There are [paths or roads along many levees](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-levee-exploring-possibilities-177697) but it's not a requirement.